# Disparo como el arpón del juego pang o super pang en libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Me gustaría hacer un disparo continuo al igual que se hace en el juego pang o super pang, ahora mismo puedo emular un disparo simple como si fueran balas de pistola pero no se me ocurre cómo hacer un disparo continuo desde donde toco la pantalla hasta que se destruya con el techo o contra algún objeto.

Estoy usando *Scene2D* y *Box2D* y esta es mi clase *Actor disparo*.

```
public class ActorDisparo extends Actor {

   private TextureRegion textureDisparo = new TextureRegion();
   private World world;
   public static Body body;
   private FixtureDef fdef;
   private String userData;
   private float anchoDisparo, altoDisparo;
   private float positionX,positionY;
   private static float porcentajeDeancho = 0,anchoMediano = 0, anchoPequeno = 0, anchoDiminuto = 0;
   private TextureRe arponRegion = new Texture();

   public ActorDisparo(World world, Texture disparo, Vector2 position, float anchoDisparo, float altoDisparo, float fuerzaX, float fuerzaY, String userData){
       this.textureDisparo = disparo;
       this.world = world;
       this.anchoDisparo = anchoDisparo;
       this.altoDisparo = altoDisparo;
       this.userData = userData;

       BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
       bodyDef.position.set(position);
       bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
       body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

       PolygonShape shapeDisparo = new PolygonShape();
       shapeDisparo.setAsBox((anchoDisparo/2)/2,altoDisparo/2);

       fdef = new FixtureDef();
       fdef.shape = shapeDisparo;
       //fdef.restitution = 0.70f;

       fdef.filter.categoryBits = BolasGame.DISPARO_BIT;
       fdef.filter.maskBits = BolasGame.BOLAROJA_BIT |
                       BolasGame.TECHO_BIT;

       body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(userData);
       shapeDisparo.dispose();
       body.setGravityScale(0f);
       body.applyLinearImpulse(fuerzaX,fuerzaY,position.x,position.y,true);

       setSize( anchoDisparo *BolasGame.MetrosAPixels  ,altoDisparo*BolasGame.MetrosAPixels);

       //setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
   }
   public float getPositionX() {
       return getPositionX();
   }

   public float getPositionY() {
       return getPositionY();
   }

   @Override
   public void act(float delta) {
      super.act(delta);
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
      super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
      setPosition( (body.getPosition().x * BolasGame.MetrosAPixels) -     getWidth()/2, (body.getPosition().y * BolasGame.MetrosAPixels) - getHeight()/2);
      batch.draw(textureDisparo,getX(),getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
   }

   public void detach(){
      world.destroyBody(body);
      remove();
   }

}
```

Y esta es la llamada que hago a la clase actor disparo.

```
if(Gdx.input.justTouched() && hasdisparado == false){
    hasdisparado =true;
    touch = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);

    stage.getCamera().unproject(touch);

    actorDisparo = new ActorDisparo(world,textureDisparo,new Vector2(touch.x/BolasGame.MetrosAPixels,touch.y/BolasGame.MetrosAPixels),20/BolasGame.MetrosAPixels,40/BolasGame.MetrosAPixels,0,2f,BolasGame.USERDATA_DISPARO);
    stage.addActor(actorDisparo);
}
```

La textura es una imagen de *446x20* que representa el arpón completo.

```
textureDisparo = new Texture("gfx/disparo.png");
```

Ahora mismo podría posicionarlo en x donde toque con el dedo y en `y=0` y saldría desde abajo a arriba como un arpón, pero lo que quiero es que el disparo aparezca dinámicamente desde donde hago el touch con el dedo y se vaya generando secuencialmente, pero no lo consigo, sería emular el disparo del juego pang o super pang que se genera dependiendo de donde esté el jugador y desde abajo a arriba teniendo en cuenta los contactos con las bolas y el techo o el tope que tenga.

Comment: Usa una `TextureRegion` para el `Sprite` del arpón en vez de un `Texture` y cambia la altura del `TextureRegion` conforme actualizas la posición del arpón. Puedes hacer lo que te digo fijándote en la [wiki de LibGDX](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch%2C-Textureregions%2C-and-Sprites).

Comment: La cosa va por ahí, pero no consigo la forma de hacerlo correctamente con el código que tengo hasta ahora, imposible actualizar el body.createfixture(def) y el textureRegion (me creo cientos de porciones del mismo tamaño. Gracias por responder

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo bien que es lo que deseas, ¿si cada vez que el objeto bala se destruya vuelvas a disparar automaticamente mientras el boton de disapro este presionado? ¿o si es un disparo continuo como metralleta?

Para disparar nuevamente cuando el objeto bala se destruya solo hay que cambiar tu codigo un poco

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched() && hasdisparado == false){ ///no se cual es la funcion que defina presion continua, solo utilizo "isTouched()" como ejemplo
    [...]  // <-- tu mismo codigo de la funcion
}
```

despues en tu objeto bala al momento de destruirlo, tienes que cambiar la variable `hasdisparado` nuevamente a false. Cuando tu funcion `update` pase nuevamente por la seccion de codigo donde verificas la presion, la funcion `Gdx.input.isTouched()` seguira siendo `true` mientras sigas presionando el boton y se creará una bala nueva.

---

Si mas bien lo que quieres es hacer un disparo continuo como de metralleta, es necesario utilizar una variable cooldown. Cuando realizes tu primer disparo, a esa variable ponle el valor de 300 (milisegundos)
y como es un videojuego, el game refresh o update pasara varias veces por esa seccion, y cada vez que pase, reduce la variable en la cantidad de ms que pasaron desde el ultimo update.
Cuando la variable llegue nuevamente a 0, realizas otro disparo y vuelves a poner el valor 300 en tu variable cooldown.

```
int shootCooldown = 0;
[...]
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){  //no se cual es la funcion que defina presion continua, solo utilizo esto como ejemplo
    if (shootCooldown > 0)
        shootCooldown -= elapsedTime;
    if (shootCooldown <= 0){
        shootCooldown = 300;
        spawnBullet(); // <-- tu codigo para crear una bala
    }
}
```

Basicamente este seria un fragmento que te ayudaria a hacer una mecanica de disparo continuo.
Adicionalmente tendrias que terminar de reducir el cooldown del disparo en caso de que ya no se este presionando el boton, para que no se quede ese cooldown activo cuando vuelvas a presionar el boton, algo asi como:

```
if(!Gdx.input.isTouched() && shootCooldown > 0){
    shootCooldown -= elapsedTime;
    if (shootCooldown <= 0){
        shootCooldown = 0;
    }
}
```

Recuerda que el cooldown define el tiempo de espera entre un disparo y otro, no necesariamente 300 es lo que buscas, quizas algo mas rapido o mas lento. 
Esta es una manera de hacerlo, espero que te funcione

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero creo que no me explicado bien, lo que quiero es tocar la pantalla y desde ese punto hasta que toca una bola o el techo que aparezca el arpón. No es una textura con un tamaño fijo sino que va creciendo conforme sube hacia arriba. Debería ser con un TextureRegion que coja porciones de una Textura y se actualize su tamaño de alto dinamicamente y el body.createFixture(fdef) por el tema de los contactos también tendría que actualizarse, pero no tengo ni idea como. El disparo con un tamaño

Comment: Para que se me entienda lo que necesito es un disparo como el arpón del juego pang. Aquí se puede ver que es lo que quiero exactamente https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHgdXKQDfsE. En resumen es eso

Comment: Se me ocurren dos soluciones: que tengas una textura de arpon con la cadena y que de tamaño tenga la altura maximo que un arpon podria tener. Al crear el arpon, poner la textura detras del piso y solamente ir moviendola hacia arriba a la misma velocidad. La otra solucion es que cada que avance el arpon hacia arriba generes una particula que se quede en esa posicion y y que su posicion x cambie usando una formula oscilatoria, y esto daria la impresion de una cadena que oscila

Comment: Despues de ver el video, la solucion es la primera que te di (textura de arpon con cadena con una altura maxima definida que se va recorriendo hacia arriba), ya que en ese juego es lo que hace.

Comment: Si, eso ya lo he conseguido, tengo una textura de 446x20, la pongo fuera de la pantalla y cuando toco la pantalla la muestro de abajo a arriba. pero lo que quiero conseguir es que aparezca desde donde doy el toque en la pantalla. Al igual que en el juego pang que aparece dependiendo de donde esté el jugador, por ejemplo cuando sube unas escaleras aparece desde ahí y no desde abajo del todo, no se si me explico. pero vamos creo que debe de ser muy complicado hacer eso. De todas formas gracias por responder, me trae de cabeza este problema.

Comment: Para ser más claro y olvidarme del juego pang. Lo que me hace falta es una textura que crezca dinamicamente en la pantalla a la vez que sus colliders de Box2D

Comment: Ya te entendi perfectamente, No se si tu engine te permita hacerlo pero cuando dibujas una textura, defines el tamaño de la textura y el rectangulo source de donde se va a obtener `drawTexture(x,y,w,h, sourcex, sourcey, sourcew, sourceh);` Para que pueda funcionar tu procedimiento, crece la altura de la textura a dibujar al mismo tiempo que la altura origen (`h` = `sourceh`), asi siempre la textura comienza en el piso (actual) y no se dibuja enteramente en cada disparo

Comment: @SanderRito "No entiendo bien que es lo que deseas" , lo mejor es comentar en la pregunta y pedir aclaraciones para poder dar una respuesta correcta, saludos.